# What is a good upper bound for this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I'm looking to estimate the definite integral,

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\int_{x_1}^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-2}}\cdots\int_{x_{n-2}}^\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_{2}dx_1.$$

Obviously, one can show that this is less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}$. I suspect that this estimate can be greatly improved. Are there any standard approaches to a problem such as this? A hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Shall $\int_{x_{n-1}}^{1/\sqrt{n}}\,dx_n$ a) constrain $x_{n-1}$ to not exceed $1/\sqrt{n}$ or b) be negative when $x_{n-1} > 1/\sqrt{n}$? Probably the latter, but I think dealing with the negative contributions from when an odd number of $x_k > x_{k+1}$ occurs will be difficult.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks for spotting an error. The question has now been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hand-wavy:  This is an $n$-dimensional cone, so its volume is $1/n$ times the volume of the corresponding cylinder which would be the same iterated integral with all the lower bounds changed to $0$.  So I think the volume is $\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n!}}.$

Comment: Note that $0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_{n-1}<1$, so you can definitely bound the integral by the volume of the simplex, which is already $\frac 1{(n-1)!}$.